# Get all unique keys from object of objects using N1QL in Couchbase

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++

If I have documents in Couchbase which all have a property `foo` which is an object of objects (all bars) like this:

```
{
    foo: {
        bar_1: {
            prop1: "hello",
            prop2: "world"
        },
        bar_2: {
            prop1: "i'm",
            prop2: "confused"
        }
    }
}
```

Using N1QL how can I select ***all unique bars*** (just the key not the values of bar)?

I'm currently using `SELECT DISTINCT RAW OBJECT_NAMES(foo) FROM ...` which returns an array of arrays each with the list of keys from each `foo`. I'm then parsing this into a `C#` `string[][]` and flattening it and making distinct.

The `DISTINCT` means that where documents have exactly the same `bars` they aren't duplicated but often this is not the case. This means that I currently have uneeded code execution in `C#` where I'm sure there's a nice way to do it all in N1QL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNNEST the Array

```
   SELECT DISTINCT RAW n
   FROM default d
   UNNEST OBJECT_NAMES(d.foo) AS n;
```